# Backtracking to get points in maze solution

Tags: java, recursion, backtracking

So I have been trying to create a fully functioning mazegame for some while now. I implemented a maze generation algorithm that uses a DFS, I also implemented a shortest path algorithm using a DFS. Now what I am trying to do is to recite the vertices you need to travel to use the shortest path from a starting point to point B. As soon as I thought about it, I thought Backtracking, I haven't ever actually implemented a backtracker so now I am kind of lost. Here is my code, minB is the array that holds the shortest path from the point A to any other point on the maze. My logic is to try to push nodes in all 4 directions around the current node iff the shortest path difference between the two nodes is 1, if the new cell isn't a wall, and if it isn't out of bounds. Then if you have arrived at point B, congrats print out the points. If you have arrived at a point that has the same shortest path as A to B but isn't B then backtrack. Ok that there was the problem, I don't know how to take out nodes from the list "points" because what prevents you from coming back to this configuration? If my explanation isn't good just say and I will try to clarify.

```
static ArrayList<int[]> points = new ArrayList<int[]>();

public static void backtrack(int x, int y) {
    if (maze[x][y] == 'B') {
        for(int i=0;i<points.size();++i){
            System.out.println(points.get(i)[0]+" "+points.get(i)[1]);
        }
        return;
    } else if(minB[x][y]==minB[col-1][row-2]&&maze[x][y]!='B') {
        /*DONT KNOW WHAT TO DO HERE*/
        points.remove(points.size()-1);
        return;
    }else{
        int[]point={x,y};
        points.add(point);
        for (int[] dirs : dir) {
            int x1 = x + dirs[0];
            int y1 = y + dirs[1];
            if (x1 >= 0 && y1 >= 0 && y1 < row && x1 < col) {
                if (maze[x1][y1] != '#') {
                    if(minB[x1][y1]-minB[x][y]==1){
                        backtrack(x1,y1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are `minB` and `mindB` supposed to be?

Comment: For what it's worth, [Dijkstra's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) is a well-known solution for finding the shortest path between two points, so you could implement that instead.

Comment: I have already implemented dijkstra on another one of my programs...yes it does find the shortest path between two points. But it alone does not find the vertices themselves, and this is an unweighted graph so I don't need it. minB is the shortest path is the array that holds the shortest path from A to any other point in the maze.

Comment: What do you mean, "it alone does not find the vertices themselves?" Also, Dijkstra's algorithm works fine for unweighted graphs, since at that point it becomes a matter of finding the path with the least number of vertices involved.